# Corner plot: "more dimensions than samples" error

Tags: python, plot, astronomy

I am trying to make a corner plot with 5 labels. Each label is an array with 1713 values. It appears I have 2 dimensions but only 1 sample. How do I increase the number of samples?

Input:

```
# Labels: Teff, logg, [Fe/H], [Mg/Fe], and [Si/Fe]

import corner
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

hdu1 = fits.open('partb_ASPCAP&cuts.fits')
data = hdu1[1].data

samples = np.vstack([data['Teff'],data['logg'],data['FE_H'],data['MG_FE'],data['SI_FE']])
print(len(samples.shape))
print(samples.T.shape)

figure = corner.corner(samples)
```

Output:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YSuW.png)

A corner plot, aka triangle plot, has histograms along the outer diagonal (each with an x-axis of Teff or another label and with y-axis of probability). The inner plots are contour plots (each with an x-axis of one label and a y-axis of a different label).
[example of corner plot with 4 labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOIrq.png)

The corner function: https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: What's a "corner plot"?

Comment: What's the result of `samples.shape`? -- never mind, it's in your output.

Comment: What does it do if you pass in `samples.T`?

Answer (score 0):

```
figure = corner.corner(samples.T)
```